# Character movement rotating around a central point

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, controller, augmented-reality

I'm building an AR platformer test and have a specific question about constraining a characters movement to rotate in a circular motion around a central pivot point.

Currently the level builds out in a long line along x space, and so the characters movement is restricted to X movement tied to left/right controls, plus a jump button that allows him to obviously jump, so 3D space but essentially 2D movement. So the player has to walk along and follow the characters movement in X space as they move through the level.

However, I'd like to build a version where the level is circular, and surrounds the player so they can just rotate their body to track along with the characters movement. I've looked through a bunch of other forum posts but can't figure out how to apply them to my particular character setup.

Some ideas or things I've already investigated:

1. Wondering if there's a simple parenting solution where the character is parented to an empty game object, and my playerController script is adjusted to control rotation of the game object versus direction of character.
2. Done a little research into rotateAround but I don't fully understand the concept.

Current player controller code is pasted below if that provides further context.

```
using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using UnityEngine; 
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

 public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour 
 {
     //Movement
     public float speed = 10, jumpVelocity = 10;
     public LayerMask playerMask;
     public bool canMoveInAir = true;
     public AudioSource[] AudioClips = null;

     //Combat
     public int health =3;
     public float invincibleTimeAfterHurt = 2;

     //Teleporation
     //public Transform destination01;
     //public Transform destination02;
     //public Transform destination03;

     //References
     private gameMaster gm;

     Transform myTrans, tagGround;
     Rigidbody myBody;
     //GetComponent<Rigidbody> myBody;
     bool isGrounded = false;
     float hInput;
     AnimatorController myAnim;




     void Start () 
     {
         myBody = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
         myTrans = this.transform;
         tagGround = GameObject.Find (this.name + "/tag_ground").transform;
         myAnim = AnimatorController.instance;
         gm = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("gameMaster").GetComponent<gameMaster> ();
     }


     void FixedUpdate () 
     {
         isGrounded = Physics.Linecast (myTrans.position, tagGround.position, playerMask);
         myAnim.UpdateIsGrounded (isGrounded);


         #if !UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_IPHONE || UNITY_EDITOR
         Move (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"));
     myAnim.UpdateSpeed(hInput);
     if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump"))
         Jump ();
     //GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();

     #endif

     Move (hInput);
 }

 void Move(float horizontalInput)
 {
     if (!canMoveInAir && !isGrounded)
         return;

     Vector3 moveVel = myBody.velocity;
     moveVel.x = horizontalInput * speed;
     myBody.velocity = moveVel;
 }

 public void Jump()
 {
     if(isGrounded)
     myBody.velocity += jumpVelocity * Vector3.up;
     if (!AudioClips[1].isPlaying)
     {
         AudioClips[1].Play();
     }
 }

 public void StartMoving (float horizontalInput)
 {
     hInput = horizontalInput;
     myAnim.UpdateSpeed(horizontalInput);
 }

 void Hurt()
 {
     health--;
     if (health <= 0)
         //SceneManager.LoadScene (SceneManager.LoadedScene):
         //Application.LoadLevel (Application.loadedLevel);
         SceneManager.LoadScene("UnityARKitMario13", LoadSceneMode.Single);
     else
         myAnim.TriggerHurt (invincibleTimeAfterHurt);
 }

 void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collision)
 {
     Enemy enemy = collision.collider.GetComponent<Enemy> ();
     if (enemy != null) {
         if (!AudioClips[0].isPlaying)
         {
             AudioClips[0].Play();
         }
         foreach (ContactPoint point in collision.contacts) {
             Debug.Log (point.normal);
             Debug.DrawLine (point.point, point.point + point.normal, Color.red, 10);
             if (point.normal.y >= 1f) {
                 Vector3 velocity = myBody.velocity;
                 velocity.y = jumpVelocity;
                 myBody.velocity = velocity;
                 enemy.Hurt ();
             } else {
                 Hurt ();
             }
         }
     }
 }

 void OnTriggerEnter (Collider collision)
 {
     if (collision.CompareTag ("Coin")) {
         Destroy (collision.gameObject);
         gm.points += 1;
         if (!AudioClips [2].isPlaying) {
             AudioClips [2].Play ();
         }
     }
 }
```

}

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "I'd like to build a version where the level is circular, and surrounds the player so they can just rotate their body to track along with the characters movement."

Comment: So imagine you're standing in an open space and there's an invisible circle that extends outwards from you, then the characters left/right movement is tied to the circumference of that circle. Does that make sense?

Comment: So The the player is just watching the character who appears farther away, running around the circle?

Comment: Not quite sure I get it. A drawing might prove helpful for this explanation.
I get that you have a circle with you in the center, but the characters movement in relation to the circumference is something I can interpret in a variety of ways.

Is the character running around the circles circumference and you make him change direction from left to right and vice versa?

Comment: Managed to get a solution in the Unity forums but thanks for the responses here. Link here if interested: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1430065/character-movement-rotating-around-central-point.html